SSIS Packages fail after SQL Server Reboot
I have an issue, whenever my SQL Server 2019 VM is restarted at any point, all of my SSIS packages running through the SQL Job Agent fail until I perform a repair on the instance.  I can't seem to figure out what is missing to prevent this from occurring.  My SQL Server Agent and all services are running and start up automatically after the reboot with no issue, it is using a domain account and there are no problems I can see there but the jobs just fail immediately until I repair.
Any ideas as to what I can do?
Edit: The errors I receive are just straight failures, I have nothing in the job log which indicates any reason.  It just starts, then fails immediately almost as if the agent wasn't running (but it is).

"...all of my SSIS packages running through the SQL Job Agent fail...", please edit your question and elaborate on it, add error messages, etc.

What does "Repair" do?

Are you using the SQL Server Agent to start a job that contains the SSIS package? Even running the job manually (right-click -> start job at step...) will generate a history log entry. If you go into the job history, you'll see the error, and it should be expandable, and when expanded, it will have an error message and an error code. You should edit your question to include them, even if you think it doesn't indicate a reason.

I checked the logs and noted that that all jobs are in Pending Execution, hence why no errors.  I did some research on this and it seems like it might be related to a GPO policy issue.  I can't seem to figure out how to fix that though, anyone else have this happen?
